# Rollback of entirely edited question

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users, rollbacks, rollback-wars

The OP for [Python classes and reference points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605313/python-classes-and-reference-points) edited the original question with an entirely new one. After rolling it back and requesting they post a new question, they rolled back my rollback to the new question.

What is the appropriate course of action if the OP continues to insist on the edited question which makes the comments and existing answer obsolete?

Comment: Doesn’t seem like q particularly worthwhile question to keep around, though.

Comment: It might have already triggered an ["rollback war" auto-flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75906).

Comment: [A chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478)? Or perhaps this is a degree worse?

Comment: @PeterMortensen the question that I linked here is not a chameleon question, at least not in the same sense as that meta post. The edited version wad complete different rather than about a new error in the same code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The response is not to get further involved with the OP and Mod flag it with an explanation of what occurred. Let the moderator handle the situation. There is no point in getting into an edit war.

The post would probably be locked with a content dispute notice.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It appears that the OP has moved on.